# How to access the database from unit test in Fast API?

Tags: unit-testing, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm struggling accessing SQLAlchemy while unit testing in Fast API.

```
def test_successful_register_ios():
    response = client.post("/register/",headers={},json={})
    assert response.status_code == 201
    device = get_db().query(Device).get("a1")
    assert device.expires_at == mydate
```

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'query'

In my test class I'm applying all the overrides:

```
from database.database import Base
from main import app, get_db

settings = Settings()
engine = create_engine(settings.sqlalchemy_database_uri)
TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
client = TestClient(app)

def override_get_db():
    try:
        db = TestingSessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
```

I don't think `get_db().query(Device).get("a1")` is the right way to do it. But I'm quite stuck and the documentation doesn't cover this case.

Comment: It looks like `dependency_overrides` in FastAPI only works when using Dependency Injection using `Depends`. I don't see this in the supplied code.

Answer (score 22):

When you get the error `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'query'` python is telling you that the result of `get_db()` is not an sqlalchemy session object but rather a generator that yields a session object.

Try calling `next()` on your generator to get a session out of the generator.

```py
def test_successful_register_ios():
    response = client.post("/register/",headers={},json={})
    assert response.status_code == 201
    device = next(get_db()).query(Device).get("a1")
    assert device.expires_at == mydate
```

Comment: Using `next()` works however, I don't understand why this is required when using pytest. In the main fastapi app, using dependency injection with `Depends(get_db)` works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: To answer my own question: FastApi makes the initial call so that the generator yields the sqlalchemy session: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant